# Creating a dynamiclist in excel with python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I currently have a list in python that consists of countries. This list is dynamic, as it is based off a list of countries I have on a separate text file

I am trying to export the list from python to excel under the column heading 'countries'.

Because the list is dynamic I don't want to manually enter each country with xlwt.

I want the process to be dynamic in case the text file list increases or decreases

```
list_countries = ['China','Greece','Ireland','France']
```

If anyone knows how to create a dynamic list with xlwt I would greatly appreciate it.

( Essentially grab 'list_countries' and put it in excel, regardless of how many countries are in the list)

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the text file as a dataframe using pandas:

Let Countries.txt be the text file with the following contents:

```
China
Greece
Ireland
France
```

The contents can be read to a dataframe using the following lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
list_countries = pd.read_csv('Countries.txt', header = None)
list_countries.columns = ["countries"]
```

To write **list_countries** to Excel:

```
Writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Countries.xlsx')
list_countries.to_excel(Writer,'Sheet1', index = False)
Writer.save()
```

It will output the **Countries.xlsx** file with the country names under the column title **countries**